# Turning a List of Lists into a Dictionary of Lists at Line Breaks

Tags: python

I have a list of lists where each list is a sentence. I've tried to convert this list of lists into a dictionary of lists where there is a key for each individual sentence. My attempts to do so have given me a key for each word instead of each individual sentence. Here's a what my input looks like currently.

```
{1: '[[try', 2: 'not', 3: 'become', 4: 'man', 5: 'success', 6: 'but', 7: 
'rather', 8: 'try', 9: 'become', 10: 'man', 11: 'value]', 12: '[look', 13: 
'deep', 14: 'into', 15: 'nature', 16: 'and', 17: 'then', 18: 'you', 19: 
'will', 20: 'understand', 21: 'everything', 22: 'better]', 23: '[the', 24:
'true', 25: 'sign', 26: 'intelligence', 27: 'not', 28: 'knowledge', 29:
'but', 30: 'imagination]', 31: '[we', 32: 'cannot', 33: 'solve', 34: 'our',
 35: 'problems', 36: 'with', 37: 'the', 38: 'same', 39: 'thinking', 40: 
'used', 41: 'when', 42: 'created', 43: 'them]', 44: '[weakness', 45: 
'attitude', 46: 'becomes', 47: 'weakness', 48: 'character]', 49: '["you',
 50: 'cant', 51: 'blame', 52: 'gravity', 53: 'for', 54: 'falling', 55: 
'love"]', 56: '[the', 57: 'difference', 58: 'between', 59: 'stupidity', 60:
'and', 61: 'genius', 62: 'that', 63: 'genius', 64: 'has', 65: 'its', 66: 
'limits]]'}
```

I would like this instead:

```
{1:'[[try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try', 
'become', 'man', 'value]', 2: '[look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and',
'then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better]', 3:'[the', 
'true', 'sign', 'intelligence', 'not', 'knowledge', 'but', 'imagination]',
 4:'[we', 'cannot', 'solve', 'our', 'problems', 'with', 'the', 'same', 
'thinking', 'used', 'when', 'created', 'them]', 5: '[weakness', 'attitude',
'becomes', 'weakness', 'character]', 6:'["you', 'cant', 'blame', 'gravity', 
'for', 'falling', 'love"]', '7: [the', 'difference', 'between', 'stupidity',
'and', 'genius', 'that', 'genius', 'has', 'its', 'limits]]'}
```

Thanks in advance!

My List of Lists looks like this:

```
 ['[[try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try', 
 'become', 'man', 'value]', '[look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and', 
 'then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better]', '[the', 
 'true', 'sign', 'intelligence', 'not', 'knowledge', 'but', 'imagination]',
 '[we', 'cannot', 'solve', 'our', 'problems', 'with', 'the', 'same', 
 'thinking', 'used', 'when', 'created', 'them]', '[weakness', 'attitude', 
 'becomes', 'weakness', 'character]', '["you', 'cant', 'blame', 'gravity', 
 'for', 'falling', 'love"]', '[the', 'difference', 'between', 'stupidity', 
 'and', 'genius', 'that', 'genius', 'has', 'its', 'limits]]']
```

Comment: I think your desired output is incorrect... unless I totally misunderstand. You want a key (integer) mapped to a list of tokens (not the string you have shown)? I.e., `{1: ['try', ..., 'value'], 2: ['look', ...]}` Or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to have an integer variable that you add one to every time you create a key, like so

```
x = [['try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try','become', 'man', 'value'],
     ['look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and','then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better']]

newdct = {}
dct_key = 1
for sublist in x:
    newdct [dct_key] = sublist
    dct_key += 1
dct_key = 1
```

this prints out the lists in order:

```
for k in newdct:
    print (newdct [dct_key])
    dct_key += 1
```

prints ['try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try', 'become', 'man', 'value']
['look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and', 'then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better']

this prints the whole dictionary

```
print (newdct)
```

prints 
{1: ['try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try', 'become', 'man', 'value'], 2: ['look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and', 'then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better']}

to make them single strings for each dictionary key:

```
for k in newdct:
    newdct [k] = ' '.join(newdct [k])
print (newdct)
```

prints {1: 'try not become man success but rather try become man value', 2: 'look deep into nature and then you will understand everything better'}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i = "hi world\n this is python\nyo"

sentences = i.split("\n")
index = 1
my_map = {}
for sentence in sentences:
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    my_map[index] = words
    index += 1
print(my_map)
```

And just replace i with your input. This divides the input by the new line character and then for each sentence maps the list of words to the index.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, it does increase. `index += 1`

Comment: ah I see it now, my bad.

Comment: No worries, enumerate is a better way for sure

Answer (score 0):

Without considering punctuation...which I saw you were handling in a previous post:

```
# This is whatever your list of sentences is (before its broken into words)
sentence_list = ['hey there', 'how bout that', 'lookie here']
# Make a new dict based on the size of the sentence_list
d = dict.fromkeys(range(1, len(sentence_list) + 1))
# Loop over the sentence_list to fill in the values for the dict
for ix, sentence in enumerate(sentence_list):
    # Assign each associated key to a list of words per sentence
    d[ix+1] = sentence.split()

# result is:
{1: ['hey', 'there'], 2: ['how', 'bout', 'that'], 3: ['lookie', 'here']}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify @new_to_coding's answer, try using the `zip` method, which in this case will take two lists, and "zip" corresponding elements together into a dictionary:

```
>>> x = [['try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try','become', 'man', 'value'],
         ['look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and','then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better']]
>>> dict(zip(range(1, len(x) + 1), x))
{1: ['try', 'not', 'become', 'man', 'success', 'but', 'rather', 'try', 'become', 'man', 'value'], 2: ['look', 'deep', 'into', 'nature', 'and', 'then', 'you', 'will', 'understand', 'everything', 'better']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though your question doesn't specifically state what your original list looks like, to answer your question I'm going to assume it looks like this

```
sentence_list = [['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'one'], ['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'two']]
```

to create a dictionary where the key is the number of the inside list

```
word_dict = {}


for i in range(len(sentence_list)):
    word_dict[i] = sentence_list[i]
```

to which a call to print(word_dict) would return the following

```
{0: ['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'one'], 1: ['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'two']}
```

if you wanted the dictionary to start at one the code would look like this:

```
word_dict = {}

for i in range(1, len(sentence_list) + 1):
    word_dict[i] = sentence_list[i - 1]
```

to which a call print(word_dict) returns the following:

```
{1: ['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'one'], 2: ['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'two']}
```

Comment: I posted what my list of lists looks like. I tried all the answers but I'm still getting the undesired output. Is something wrong with my list of lists?

Comment: Yes, your list of list is somehow stored inside a string in the example you posted in your post. See the apostrophes before and after your list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a list of lists.  Rather you have a list of strings. Note:

```
list_of_lists = [['hello','world'],['test','case']]
```

Is not the same as

```
list_of_strings = ['[hello','world]','[test','case]']
```

The answers listed will work nicely for sentences formatted for in the style of list_of_lists but not so well in the list of strings format.  I would recommend redoing whatever method returns your current list such that it creates a true list of lists. Then come back and apply the methods used in this thread.  This would likely result in the most elegant solution.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks so much. Any easy way to turn a list of strings into a true list of lists?

Comment: Because the format of your list of strings is not standard, there isn't some sort of built in way to do this, if that's what you're looking for.  You could conceivably create a function that parses through the strings and creates a list of lists by noting where the brackets appear.  I would really recommend modifying whatever function builds your current list of strings however.